# Combine multiple and contidtional ng-style

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I want to combine 2 styles in my ng-style, one of them is conditional style.

```
ng-style="{'height':height + '%'}"

ng-style="hasScroll !== 0 && {'width': (tableWidth) + 'px'}"
```

How can I combine both of them without override the width in case the condition is false?

the following isn't good since it's override 'width' property if the condition is falsefalse:

```
ng-style="{ 'height': height + '%', 'width': hasScroll !== 0 ? (tableWidth) + 'px' : undefined }"
```

Comment: In second ng-style  is not that && to be a question mark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-style="hasScroll !== 0 && {'width': (tableWidth) + 'px'} || { 'height': height + '%'}"
```

Working example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.has = 1;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-style=" has != 0 && {'cursor':'pointer','background-color':'blue'} || {'background-color':'blue'} ">
  kick
</div>
```

Comment: That's not good since it will apply only one of the styles always

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The answer was in your comment itself. It will implement one of those two always. So with slight modification, its working now. :)

Comment: I used the following: 
    ng-style="hasScroll !== 0 ? {'width': (tableWidth) + 'px', 'height': maxHeight} :
                   {'height': maxHeight}"

Answer (score 2):

Then, Its better to handle your logic in controller

```
<div ng-style="getStyles()">
test data
</div>

$scope.getStyles = function () {
   var styleObj = {};
   styleObj['height'] = height + '%';
   if ($scope.hasScroll !== 0) {
     styleObj['width'] = tableWidth + 'px';
   }
   return styleObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try but it is not easy to read :

```
ng-style="{ 'height':height + '%', 'width': hasScroll !== 0 ? (tableWidth) + 'px' : undefined }"
```

Comment: the problem it's override 'width' property if the condition is false

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it like this:

`ng-style="{ width: hasScroll !== 0 ? tableWidth : 0, height: height }"`

Comment: the problem it's override 'width' property if the condition is false

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple properties by doing with `,` separation

```
<div ng-style="{ 'height': height + '%', 'width': hasScroll !== 0 ? (tableWidth) + 'px' : undefined }">
test data
</div>
```

Comment: the problem it's override 'width' property if the condition is false

Comment: instead of `undefined` you can set to some default value